# LINQ - Add static text to each result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have an array of files, but the problem is the root path isn't attached to the file, so using the data below, how would I go about appending the linq item to the static string?

```
string rootPath = "C:\\Users\\MyUserName";

List<string> files = new List<string>();
files.Add("\\My Documents\\File1.txt");
files.Add("\\My Documents\\File2.txt");
```

I essentially want a list that is Path.Combine(rootPath, x);  I tried this but no luck:

```
var fileList = (from x in files
               select Path.Combine(rootPath, x)).ToList();
```

But it doesn't append the rootPath, fileList is the same as the files list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently `Path.Combine` will ignore the first parameter if the second parameter has a leading "`\`" (this [blog entry](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/02/pathcombine-be-aware-of-slash-in-second.html) has some more info).

This should work, it uses `Path.Combine` and the [`?` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to account for leading slashes in the second parameter:

```
var fileList = (from f in files 
                select Path.Combine(rootPath, 
                f.StartsWith("\\") ? f.Substring(1) : f)).ToList();
```

Comment: -1. The worse thing to do when dealing with paths is to concatenate strings.

Comment: I'm going to agree.  I can't promise that the leading \\'s are there, hence why I wanted to use Path.Combine.

Comment: Umm... That seems like a Path.Combine issue, can't have \ start the second parameter?

Answer (score 0):

the query works fine if you change

`"\\My Documents\\File1.txt" to  @"My Documents\\File1.txt"` .

**The reason is being described in the post mentioned by Donut.**

Hence,

```
string rootPath = "C:\\Users\\MyUserName";

List<string> files = new List<string>();
files.Add(@"My Documents\\File1.txt");
files.Add(@"My Documents\\File2.txt");

var fileList = (from x in files select Path.Combine(rootPath, x)).ToList(); 

OR

var fileList = files.Select(i => Path.Combine(rootPath, i));
```

works fine.

If at all you donot want to change the existing source , *then instead of Path.Combine use 
string.Concat*

e.g.

```
string rootPath = "C:\\Users\\MyUserName";

List<string> files = new List<string>();
files.Add("\\My Documents\\File1.txt");
files.Add("\\My Documents\\File2.txt");

var fileList = (from x in files select string.Concat(rootPath, x)).ToList(); 

OR
var fileList = files.Select(i => string.Concat(rootPath, i));
```

Hope this helps